# Android Webview touch content

Tags: javascript, android

I want to get the content of that tag which I touch in webview in string.

Suppose I have 5 paragraph and I touch on one then I want content of that paragraph in string.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well this is very easy, but you need to do it in parts, and you would need JavaScript.

1.- Enable JavaScript in your webview.

```
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //"web" is the object of type WebView
```

2.- Create a JavaScript Interface between the WebView and the Html.

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    public void getParagraph(final String paragraph){
        myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something with the String
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Inside the method run, you will add whatever you need to process with the String retrieved from the Html. This class can be created inside the class where you create the WebView or as a separate class if you are going to use this same behavior from another activity.

3.- Send the Interface to the WebView.

```
web.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "android");
/* In this case "android" is the name that you will use from the Html to call 
your methods if is not too clear yet, please keep reading */
```

4.- You need to add the onClick event handler to each of your P tags.

```
<p onclick="android.getParagraph(this.innerText);">Text inside the paragraph</p>
/*android was the name we set for the interface in step 3, getParagraph is the name
of the method created on step2,"this.innerText" retrieves the text inside the paragraph*/
```

**NOTE:** All the names that you see on my example can be changed, BUT if you change the name on the java class remember to change all the calls in the html

Comment: I did read the documentation. But I have have only used that method once, and it was for something slightly different, I thought maybe the extra might contain the paragraph string when the type was `UNKNOWN_TYPE`. But did not have time to test that theory so I figured I'd share it with OP in-case it could help them. Anywho this looks like a nice solution thank for sharing.

Comment: your welcome [@FoamyGuy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/507810/foamyguy), i know you did it with good things in mind :D